# Primefaces field update button

Tags: java, jsp, primefaces

I have a simple primefaces page for listing orders information

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3><h:outputText value="#{orderView.date.month}, #{orderView.date.dayOfMonth} #{orderView.date.year}"/></h3>
    <h:form>
        <c:forEach items="#{orderView.orders}" var="order">
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" skipDetailIfEqualsSummary="true"/>
            <p:panel id="basic" header="Order ##{order.id} for #{order.customerName} from #{order.customerAddress}, #{order.date}"
                     footer="Total: #{order.totalPrice}" style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                    <c:forEach items="#{order.orderDetails}" var="detail">
                        <h:outputText value="#{detail.rowId}. #{detail.serialNumber} #{detail.amount} pcs"/>
                        <hr/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{itemView.getItemInfo(detail.serialNumber)}"/>
                        <hr/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And I need a button which would update this string `<h:outputText value="#{itemView.getItemInfo(detail.serialNumber)}"/>` for the whole list. But since it's in a double foreach cycle how do I manage assign this field to button action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a style called observe-update to your output text like...

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{itemView.getItemInfo(detail.serialNumber)}" 
              styleClass="observe-update"/>
```

Then in your button for your update="" to update do this...

```xml
<p:commandButton update="@(.observe-update)" ...
```

Its a clever trick using the Observer pattern by having PF Search Expression find all components that match that style and update them.